# Персональная подпись файлов

Tags: javascript, node.js, безопасность

У меня есть сервер (`express.js`), откуда пользователи скачивают файлы, обычно это `.zip` арихивы. Я бы хотел обезопасить себя от пираства и иметь возможно узнать кто скачал конкретный файл.

Есть ли возможность как-то подписывать файлы для каждого пользователя персонально, встроить в `.zip` архив ID пользователя в момент скачивания?

Comment: Сделать то можно по разному, но потом любую защиту можно будет убрать\обойти.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, я это понимаю. Меня интересую простые методы, но незаметные на первый взгляд. Мои пользователи вряд ли будут пытататься как-то обойти защиту

Comment: А смысл? Ну скачаю я архив и распакую. И нет больше никакой подписи

Comment: А вообще в zip-файлах есть комментарии

Comment: @AlexeyTen Если человек качает архивы не для себя и сразу же распространяет их, то есть вероятность он не будет распаковывать все архивы и запаковывать снова

Comment: Насколько мне известно ни один из "пользовательских" архиваторов не поддерживает встроенные подписи на основе открытых/закрытых ключей. Так что, перед отправкой архива пользователю, генерируйте в архиве коментарий с неким пользовательским идентификатором.